# Build issue when using prebuilt libraries with the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a program I am porting that links together multiple libraries when creating the executable.  I have built all those libraries using the stand alone toolchain and using the standalone toolchain I am able to create an executable that works on an android device.  So, it seems like the libraries I have built are functional.  Now I am trying to incorporate those libraries with an app.  So, in my android.mk I have something like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ROOT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH = $(ROOT_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := test-libs

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := staticA
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := sharedA sharedB sharedC sharedD
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test-libs.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

For each of the libraries, I have a Android.mk like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := sharedA

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sharedA.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I then build my project (in eclipse), I get this:

```
C:/ndk/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a(unwind-arm.o): In function `__gnu_unwind_pr_common':
/cygdrive/c/ndk/android-ndk-r7b/build/core/build-binary.mk:314: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/libtest-libs.so' failed
/tmp/ndk-digit/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.4.3/libgcc/../gcc/config/arm/unwind-arm.c:1237: undefined reference to `__cxa_call_unexpected'
```

Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Also, the static library and one of the shared libraries have no dependencies on anything and if I only include them all is cool.  One of my shared libraries only had a dependency on the static library.  If I only include those, but when I include the others, which have dependencies on other shared libraries, this problem occurs.

Update 1:  Ok it appears to be because the APP_STL setting in my Application.mk was being ignored.  All I have in my Application.mk is:
    APP_STL := gnustl_shared
If I copy over the libgnustl_shared.so and treat it like another prebuilt shared lib, my problem is gone.  Any idea why the APP_STL is not working properly.  Note, I could have screwed something up.  I just upgraded to using 7b.  Using gnustl_shared used to work for me with other apps.  Rolling back to 7 doesn't fix it.  I think I have messed something up in Eclipse.  I use Eclipse (windows) with sequoyah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the linker is giving you an error. What you should do is the following:

Add a LOCAL_LDLIBS under your LOCAL_MODULE := test-libs. Here you need to include all the libraries you link against when you compile your pre-compiled libraries. So for example:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lgnustl_shared -lgcc -llog -landroid -lstdc++
```

Basically you need to identify what library contains the function __cxa_call_unexpected. A quick google shows that it's probably in libstdc++. Make sure that you also link with this library when creating your pre-compiled libraries.

Comment: I have this in my Application.mk  APP_STL := gnustl_shared  if I add -lgnustl_shared to the LOCAL_LDLIBS it tells me it is not found.  In fact, if I look in the libs directory, gnustl_shared was not copied into there.  This is using NDK 7b windows install.  Any thoughts on why it is not pulling it over?  There was a problem in NDK 7, maybe it still exists.

Comment: If I copy over libgnustl_shared.so somewhat manually, by treating it like another prebuilt, everything is fine and it fixes my original issue, so I think you were onto the problem.  Any idea why adding APP_STL setting didn't do this for me.  Past experience tells me it "should" have.

Comment: I agree with you, it really should have, and I have no idea why it doesn't. It feels like a bug with the NDK. Weird things like this have made me link to all libraries everywhere more or less :P

Comment: By the way, you don't have to copy any libraries. Just supply the path to the library in LOCAL_LDLIBS using -L<path>.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it might have something to do with exceptions support.

Are you using exceptions in your code and if so are you compiling with a runtime library that supports exceptions? (and compiling with exceptions on)?.

There is more on this in the CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT and STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN files in the ndk docs.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it was related to not linking to gnustl_shared.  See other answer and my update.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed a similar problem when one of my projects which contains only C source files (*.c) references another project that contains a c++ file(*.cpp). Application.mk files for both projects had APP_STL := gnustl_shared in them. The ndk version is ndk7e.

The solution was adding an empty C++ file (dummy.cpp)  to the project that contained only .c files. Supposedly ndk understood that this project should be linked against the gnustl_shared and the build succeeded.